# Access Joined Table Latest Record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

i have this database schema as shown in the attached image, I need to somehow join `tblDdiNumbers` with `tblTransactions` showing only the latest record from `tblTransactions` and no duplicated ddi_numbers.

basically what i am trying to do is display allocated and unallocated ddi_numbers based on the information in the transaction table.

so if ddi_number X has an entry in the transaction table i can determine that it has been used and is no longer free.

or do you think it is maybe better to hold foreign keys of the information i want in the `tblDdiNumber` table instead?

[image]

Comment: This is what i have at the moment

SELECT    tblTransactions.ddi_id,  Last(tblTransactions.trans_dt) AS MaxOftrans_dt, tblDdiNumbers.ddi_number, tblTransactions.main_customer_id
FROM tblDdiNumbers INNER JOIN tblTransactions ON tblDdiNumbers.ddi_id = tblTransactions.ddi_id
GROUP BY  tblTransactions.ddi_id, tblDdiNumbers.ddi_number, tblTransactions.main_customer_id

but it returns multiple lines for each ddi_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "latest row" you're looking for *might* be given by this query. (Without knowing the keys, I'm not going to bet on it. Edit your question to include the keys.)

```
select ddi_id, max(trans_date) latest_date
from tblTransactions
group by ddi_id
```

If that query returns more than one row, then your table structure might not support what you're trying to do.

Anyway, you can join that query like this

```
select t1.*, t3.ddi_number
from tblTransactions t1
inner join (select ddi_id, max(trans_date) latest_date
            from tblTransactions
            group by ddi_id) t2
        on t1. ddi_id = t2.ddi_id
       and t1. trans_date = t2.latest_date
inner join tblDdiNumbers t3
        on t3.ddi_id = t2.ddi_id
```

Comment: Thats not working, i guess the easiest thing to do is just change the table schema, thanks for trying